# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.enterDrag()'

Tags: android

I have this strange crash reported on Crashlytics. I've never reproduced it myself. It only happens on Android 6.0.1. The entire stack trace doesn't have a single one of my lines of code so I have no idea where to even start to track it. Any ideas?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.enterDrag()' on a null object reference
       at android.widget.Editor.selectCurrentWordAndStartDrag(Editor.java:1773)
       at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:1026)
       at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:9230)
       at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:21129)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Did you able to resolve this issue ? I am also facing the same.

Comment: I did but my case was kind of weird. I change the size of the edit text on focus. Users were long pressing the edit text to copy paste and I was changing the size which cause the crash. I solved it by doing a `view.post()` in order to change the size. Actually I do a lot more things to the edit text and the layout around it but I always assumed it was the size change  that cause the error.